# Video are not updaing on vzaar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, vzaar-api

Hi I am using Rails, vzaar gem to upload the video.

title, description are updating but video file is not updating in vzaar. Any help would be appreciated.

### video_controller:

```
def edit
  @course = Course.find(params[:course_id])
  @video = @course.videos.find(params[:id])
end

def update
@course = Course.find(params[:course_id])
@video = @course.videos.find(params[:id])

api = Vzaar::Api.new(:application_token => "my token", :login => "myloginname")
api.edit_video(@video.vzaar_id, :path => params[:video][:video].tempfile.path, :title => params[:video][:title])
if @video.update_attributes(:title => params[:video][:title])
  redirect_to :back
 end
end
```

**title** is updating but video with **path** is not updating. However with same technique i successfully created video in vzaar.

Thanks

Comment: Add a link to vzaar gem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to replace the actual video content here - is that correct?

If that's the case, it's not the `edit_video` method that you need to use in this case. As our documentation states, you can only change `title`, `description`, `private` and `seo_url` that way.

To replace a video, you'll need to use the `upload_video` method again, but supply a `replace_id` in the options that marks the video id you want to overwrite. In your case, it'll look something like this:

```
api.upload_video(path: params[:video][:video].tempfile.path, title: params[:video][:title], replace_id: @video.vzaar_id)
```

You'd also need to set the other options to match your previous uploads.

I hope this helps, and please let me know if you have any questions, or alternatively contact us on support@vzaar.com. And don't forget to check out the [documentation](https://github.com/vzaar/vzaar-api-ruby), as that lists all the arguments available for each method.

All the best,
Dan

Comment: Yes i want to replace the actual video content. Thanks so much for your response. I am using this service for my educational website. Today I tried the code with replace_id. Instead of replacing the video, video removed from vzaar. What other options you suggest to match previous uploads. I simply using title && video.